# tcl check in File of Duplicates

Tags: bash, sorting, tcl

I have in the file.txt this and 2 Varibles

```
var as example 
$song RIDE
$artist TWENTY_ONE_PILOTS
```

### file.txt

```
1483379340 02.01.2017 18:49:00 GURU_JOSH_PROJECT INFINITY_08
1483379370 02.01.2017 18:49:30 LADY_GAGA MILLION_REASONS
1483379440 02.01.2017 18:50:40 GURU_JOSH_PROJECT INFINITY_08
1483379565 02.01.2017 18:52:45 GURU_JOSH_PROJECT INFINITY_08
1483379645 02.01.2017 18:54:05 POLO_HOFER ALPEROSE
1483380245 02.01.2017 19:04:05 WINCENT_WEISS MUSIK_SEIN
1483380485 02.01.2017 19:08:05 MR_PROBZ WAVES
1483380625 02.01.2017 19:10:25 ZARA_LARSSON LUSH_LIFE
1483380695 02.01.2017 19:11:35 MR_PROBZ WAVES
1483380725 02.01.2017 19:12:05 ZARA_LARSSON LUSH_LIFE
1483380765 02.01.2017 19:12:45 ARIANA_GRANDE SIDE_TO_SIDE
1483380835 02.01.2017 19:13:55 ZARA_LARSSON LUSH_LIFE
1483380975 02.01.2017 19:16:15 TWENTY_ONE_PILOTS RIDE
1483381216 02.01.2017 19:20:16 TAYLOR_SWIFT SHAKE_IT_OFF
```

I want on this day between 08:00 and 17:00 And at least 5 minutes apart (duplicat/wrong Records), check of duplicates. Of its runnng the same Song

in bash have this tested, how can set in a Tcl ?
    sort file.txt | grep '02.01.2017 08:\| 09:\| 10:\| 11:\| 12:\| 13:\| 14:\| 15:\| 16:' | cut -d " " -f4 | uniq -cd

But it does not work that way. I need a new idea pls :)

```
proc check { nick uhost handle channel text } {
    set artist TWENTY_ONE_PILOTS
    set song RIDE
    set file [exec sort file.txt | grep '02.01.2017 08:\| 09:\| 10:\| 11:\| 12:\| 13:\| 14:\| 15:\| 16:' | cut -d " " -f4 | uniq -cd]
    putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :duplicates $artist $song";        
}
```

Comment: is there a specific reason for the `bash` tag?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Tcl uses `{`…`}` instead of `'`…`'`. That might fix things.

```
set file [exec sort file.txt | grep {02.01.2017 08:\| 09:\| 10:\| 11:\| 12:\| 13:\| 14:\| 15:\| 16:} | cut -d " " -f4 | uniq -cd]
```

However, I'd do the processing directly in Tcl if I wanted to find non-unique values:

```
set f [open file.txt]
set lines [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

foreach line $lines {
    lassign [split $line] id day time artist song
    lappend info($artist,$song) $line
}

foreach {key matches} [array get info] {
    if {[llength $matches] > 1} {
        # Now have a list of duplicates; the oldest might be first if file.txt is so sorted

        # Write some reporting code here
    }
}
```

Comment: I was working under the assumption that the first column is a timestamp, in which case it should be easy to calculate the interval.

Answer (score 0):

I either missed that the interval should be ≥ 5 minutes (I thought it was < 5 minutes), or the question has changed. This code checks for events when the same song is played at ≥ 5 minutes intervals, and prints out those events. None of the lines in the given data match these conditions, but if I add some more occurrences of a song it seems to work.

```
proc enumerate times {
    set times [dict values $times]
    if {[llength $times] == 2} {
        return "[lindex $times 0] and [lindex $times 1]"
    } else {
        return "[join [lrange $times 0 end-1] ", "], and [lindex $times end]"
    }
}

proc input name {
    set f [open $name]
    set data [read $f]
    close $f
    string trim $data
}

proc checkHours {time early late} {
    if {[scan $time %d hour] != 1} {
        error "bad time value?"
    }
    if {$hour < $early || $hour >= $late} {
        return -code continue
    }
}

proc main {} {
    set items {}
    foreach line [split [input file.txt] \n] {
        lassign $line seconds - time - song

        checkHours $time 8 17

        if {[dict exists $items $song]} {
            dict for {secs -} [dict get $items $song] {
                if {$seconds - $secs >= 300} {
                    dict set items $song $seconds $time
                }
            }
        } else {
            dict set items $song $seconds $time
        }
    }
    dict for {song times} $items {
        if {[llength $times] > 2} {
            puts "$song played ≥five minutes apart at [enumerate $times]"
        }
    }
}

main
```

The `enumerate` command is just for prettyprinting times.

Documentation:
[- (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[== (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[> (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[>= (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm),
[dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm),
[lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm),
[lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm),
[llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/llength.htm),
[lrange](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lrange.htm),
[open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[read](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/read.htm),
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm),
[scan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/scan.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: Hello Peter Lewerin big thx for the script this working, I think we have wrong understand. I would like only the output when the song played on this day between 08:00-17:00. and ignore when within 5mininis. I would like to spend double songs, regards

Comment: @Tobi: how about now?

Comment: can i make this in a proc ? to can start from a another proc? when i load so as new tcl have not annouce, regards